# Dry run for Python in Kubernetes API Client Operations

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have been coding some operations that I need to perform in **Kubernetes** with the **[Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)** official library.

One example is the patch of a service to update the value of a label:

```py
# Code to instantiate the api object. 
config.load_kube_config()
self.v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
```

```py
# Code to call the patch function
def patch_namespaced_service(self, name, namespace, body, dry_run=True):
    logging.debug(body)
    response = self.v1.patch_namespaced_service(name, namespace, body, dry_run=dry_run)
    logging.info("Service patched. status='%s'" % str(response.status))
```

It works like a charm but the `dry_run` option is never applied and no matter what value I sent, it always performs the patch.

This is the source code where is documented the `dry_run` parameter:

```py
def patch_namespaced_service(self, name, namespace, body, **kwargs):  # noqa: E501
        """patch_namespaced_service  # noqa: E501

        partially update the specified Service  # noqa: E501
        This method makes a synchronous HTTP request by default. To make an
        asynchronous HTTP request, please pass async_req=True
        >>> thread = api.patch_namespaced_service(name, namespace, body, async_req=True)
        >>> result = thread.get()

        :param async_req bool
        :param str name: name of the Service (required)
        :param str namespace: object name and auth scope, such as for teams and projects (required)
        :param UNKNOWN_BASE_TYPE body: (required)
        :param str pretty: If 'true', then the output is pretty printed.
        :param str dry_run: When present, indicates that modifications should not be persisted. An invalid or unrecognized dryRun directive will result in an error response and no further processing of the request. Valid values are: - All: all dry run stages will be processed
        :param str field_manager: fieldManager is a name associated with the actor or entity that is making these changes. The value must be less than or 128 characters long, and only contain printable characters, as defined by https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsPrint. This field is required for apply requests (application/apply-patch) but optional for non-apply patch types (JsonPatch, MergePatch, StrategicMergePatch).
        :param bool force: Force is going to \"force\" Apply requests. It means user will re-acquire conflicting fields owned by other people. Force flag must be unset for non-apply patch requests.
        :return: V1Service
                 If the method is called asynchronously,
                 returns the request thread.
        """
```

I would like to remark this part:

```
Valid values are: - All: all dry run stages will be processed
```

In other parts of the documentation they use `dry_run` as a list:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1DeleteOptions.md

But I have tried `dry_run=True`, `dry_run="All"` and `dry_run=["All"]` without success.

Does anyone have an idea about how to perform this operation with a `dry_run`?

Comment: What is your Kubernetes cluster version?

Comment: The version is: 1.10

Comment: According to the documentation, it should be a list of strings. Have you tried declaring the list before using it as parameter?

Comment: are you sure that Kubernetes v1.10 supports dry-run option?

Comment: I have using the dry-run with apply in the cli, seems like is not supported for patch but I don't understand they client library has the option.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this and works fine with kubernetes package v25.3.0

```
kwargs = {"name": doc['metadata']['name'], "body":doc, "namespace":doc['metadata']['namespace'], "dry_run":"All"}
ret = getattr(v1, "patch_namespaced_config_map")(**kwargs)
```